# UIPageViewController delegate method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

In my application I have a **RootViewController (UIPageViewController), a FirstController (UIViewController) and a SecondController (UIViewController).**
The two views inside the two **UIViewControllers scroll over the RootViewController**.

In my RootViewController.h:

```
@interface RootController : UIPageViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
```

But when I scroll between different views delegate methods like:

```
-(void) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
```

are not called.
Why? Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you assign rootViewController (whichever controller/object you want to receive the delegate calls) to be the delegate/datasource of the UIPageViewController?

```
pageViewController.delegate = rootViewController;
pageViewController.dataSource = rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the obvious solution above, if you are encountering this issue please consider the possibility that the PageViewController itself is not being retained.  I made the mistake earlier this evening of instantiating a PageViewController and adding its view as a subView but not retaining the pageViewController itself.

Make sure to retain it either by adding it as a childViewController or assigning it to a strong property.

Comment: I was adding it to a `UICollectionReusableView` so I couldn't add it as childViewController. So assigning to a strong property did it. thanks

Comment: I realized that I added the UIPageViewController as method var rather than instance variable which was creating the issue for me.

Comment: Thats exactly what was happening with me. The moment I took a strong reference of the page controller in my tableviewcell the code started working. thanks.

Comment: This exactly happened to me today. Good thing I saw this answer and it saved my day figuring out why it's not working

Comment: I just spend 5 hours trying to fix this... Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just spent some time trying to figure out why didFinishAnimating was not called. My delegates were set right but it turns out that in Swift 3 the function goes like that :

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```

Mind the above underscore. The function below won't be called.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you connect the page view controller's delegate outlet? My guess is that you never connected the delegate link.

It's odd to have a page view controller be it's own data source and delegate. I've never tried to do that, as you are doing, and am not sure it would work. I always set up a container view controller that manages the page view controller. With storyboards you just set up a container view in IB and connect an embed segue. Then you'd make the container view controller the data source and/or delegate.

Comment: I just did some testing on this as I was having the page view controller be its own dataSource. If you try to set dataSource in viewDidLoad your delegate methods will never get called. However if you do your own init and set dataSource after calling the super init method the delegate methods are called. I don't like overriding the init so I'll switch to the container view strategy but thought I'd let others know that that's one work around