# UIPageViewController as subview with double page in landscape and single page in portrait

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

**My task:** I need to implement a `UIPageViewController` with `TransitionStyle.pageCurl`. In portrait it should display a single page and double page in landscape. It should also be possible to pinch-to-zoom on both pages (when double page) and not just on one at a time.

**My solution thus far**: I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UIScrollView`. I then add a `UIPageViewController` view to my scroll view like this: `self.scrollView.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)`.

**My problem:** When I rotate the device `func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, spineLocationFor orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> UIPageViewController.SpineLocation` isn't called and therefore I am unable to change between double page and single page, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868768/2501509. My problem was that I did not retain the `UIPageViewController` itself but only its view. By adding the page viewController to my viewController my issue was solved: `self.addChild(self.pageViewController)`.